# Theanos Installation error linux compilation error

Tags: python, linux, theano

So I was trying to setup theano on my Linux14.04 machine . 
Steps done so far :

- Installed miniconda
- installed dependencies - `conda install numpy scipy mkl <nose> <sphinx> <pydot-ng>`
- Did not install the GPU drivers .... do not need the higher computation as of now.
- Tried installing theano with : `<sudo> pip install <--user> Theano[test, doc]`

It exited with the following error :
[Theano terminal error gist](https://gist.github.com/crazysal/2c1990360a4ca0750d182e4217de998d)

Been trying to solve the same, max online references are related to upgrading pip : 
Ran this : 
`pip install --upgrade pip 
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

Package error : 
Solved by installing :

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Gave error for installing dependencies Theano[test, doc] : 
Clean install with only :

```
sudo pip install Theano
```